# Not finding how to use a search result term in link attributes in oracle apex 22.2 search page

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

Im using apex 22.2 And with it comes a new feature, the search page, with its search configurations attached, I am implementing this into a project and having trouble using the link function as I would like, the desired result is that after searching for something that comes up in the search configuration it grabs the primary key in this case 'project_ID' and it inputs it into the 'proyect_Id' field in my target page which takes you to the correct page instead of the generic template page with no data. I understand how to do this in any other type of link but with search configurations I can't find any items that bring up what I just searched/selected from the search If anyone knows the way to do this or a workaround that helps my case it'd be much appreciated!

Ive tried browsing the items that i can set as value, using various &PRIMARY_KEY AND &PROJECT_ID type values and setting the value into an item but none of them have worked. i also cant find much info in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `&PROJECT_ID.` *with a dot at the end* as the **Value** in the Link dialog should work to select the selected project.